# Number of tracingspaths across a rectangle (filled with letters)

Tags: combinatorics

Given below is a words from the English dictionary arranged as a matrix

```
MATHE
ATHEM
THEMA
HEMAT
EMATI
MATIC
ATICS
```

Tracing the matrix is starting from the top left position and at each step move either RIGHT or DOWN, to reach the bottom right of the matrix. It is assured that any such tracing generates the same word. How many such tracings can be possible for a given word of length m+n-1 written as a matrix of size m * n?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but shouldn't the length be $m+n-2$, not $m+n-1$?

Comment: @DennisMeng nopes.It should be m+n-1  only. as in above example also the m=7 and n=5 and word is MATHEMATICS whose length is 11

Comment: Ah wait, you're right. Fencepost error on my part.

Comment: (For what it's worth, this is definitely just combinatorics. No number theory here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be consistent here, I'll assume that we're talking about $m$ rows and $n$ columns.

Each path then can be thought of as a Manhattan walk, where we have to go to the right $n-1$ times and down $m-1$ times. The total number of ways to do this is $$\binom{m+n-2}{n-1} = \binom{m+n-2}{m-1}$$ Think of it as either choosing the times we move right (left-hand side) or choosing the times we move down (right-hand side).

Comment: will you please tell how you solved it?

Comment: @user3001932 Put it this way. You have to move a total of $n + m - 2$ times, $n-1$ of which are down (and the rest are to the right). You can think of each walk as picking when you take the $n-1$ down moves among the $n+m-2$ total moves. The number of ways to pick are given by that binomial coefficient.

Comment: ok got it now.Thanx for explanation